# Grouping dataframe based on column similarities in Python

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, dataframe, grouping

I have a dataframe with commonalities in groups of column names:

> Sample1.Feature1 | Sample1.Feature2 | ... | Sample99.Feature1 | Sample99.Feature 2

And I'd like to reorder this as

> |Sample1                 .........................       | Sample99
>
> |Feature 1, Feature 2 | .....     | Feature 1, Feature 2 |

I'd then have summary stats, e.g. mean, for Feature1, Feature2, grouped by Sample#. I've played with df.groupby() with no luck so far.

I hope my lack of table formatting skills doesn't distract from the question.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

consider the dataframe `df`

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    np.ones((1, 6)),
    columns='s1.f1 s1.f2 s1.f3 s2.f1 s2.f2 s2.f3'.split())
df
```

[image]

---

- `split` the columns

---

```
df.columns = df.columns.str.split('.', expand=True)
df
```

[image]